# Is there a simple way to convert a decimal time (e.g. 1.074 minutes) into mm:ss format using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I was wondering if there's a simple way, using moment.js library, to transform a decimal time interval (for example, 1.074 minutes) into its equivalent 'mm:ss' value. I am currently using a function which doesn't work too well with negative times (it outputs the value in '-m:ss' format):

```
function secTommss(sec){
 var min = Math.floor(sec/60)
 sec = Math.round(Math.abs(sec) % 60);
 return min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec)
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is some JavaScript that will do what you are asking:

```
function minTommss(minutes){
 var sign = minutes < 0 ? "-" : "";
 var min = Math.floor(Math.abs(minutes));
 var sec = Math.floor((Math.abs(minutes) * 60) % 60);
 return sign + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
}
```

Examples:

```
minTommss(3.5)        // "03:30"
minTommss(-3.5)       // "-03:30"
minTommss(36.125)     // "36:07"
minTommss(-9999.999)  // "-9999:59"
```

You *could* use moment.js [durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), such as

```
moment.duration(1.234, 'minutes')
```

But currently, there's no clean way to format a duration in mm:ss like you asked, so you'd be re-doing most of that work anyway.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I played with moment.duration() yesterday but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: You could format a moment duration to expected format with: `moment.utc(moment.duration(duration).asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm')`

Answer (score 8):

Using moment:

```js
function formatMinutes(mins){
  return moment().startOf('day').add(mins, 'minutes').format('m:ss');
}
```

Comment: I used your answer as inspiration; ended up with the following code that transforms a value like '0.25' to '00:15': `moment().startOf('day').add(value, 'hours').format('HH:mm')`

Answer (score 3):

using just js, here's a really simple and fast way to do this for up to 12 hours:

```
function secTommss2(sec){
  return new Date(sec*1000).toUTCString().split(" ")[4]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe I am a bit late to the party, but still... my two cents:

you can build the variable in seconds, parse it as a date, and then cut it to a string or whatever format you want to use it:

```
let totalTimeInSeconds = 1.074 * 60;
let result = new Date(null, null, null, null, null, totalTimeInSeconds);
console.log(result.toTimeString().split(' ').[0].substring(3));
```

and the output will be:

```
01:14
```