# Convert decimal time to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time

I have been trying to inspect an API and it uses a `time` parameter represented in decimal to filter results. For example:

```
GET /forum/topic/ajax_json_all_topic_tag?t=0.01949887323866628
```

`t=0.01949887323866628` is the time filter. How do I convert this time filter into a Unix timestamp?

What kind of representation is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to convert a decimal time (e.g. 1.074 minutes) into mm:ss format using moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599054/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-a-decimal-time-e-g-1-074-minutes-into-mmss)

Comment: @Hitmands This is so different. Will give invalid-date if I try the first answer there using moment

Comment: You need to provide the algorithm to convert 0.01949887323866628 to a date, e.g. is it decimal hours? Or days, months or years from some epoch? As it stands, it's a meaningless number. The rest is simple.